# How does Azure functions / WebJobs extensions register a http endpoint?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-webjobs

When looking at the durable tasks framework extension for azure functions, it creates some management endpoints at `runtime/webhooks/durabletasks/instances`

And I concluded that this is the code that handles these requests:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/bf9a9b29fccae849840686459175b7d8ae619f67/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/HttpApiHandler.cs#L21

but I can't figure out how the extension register these endpoints, as i am creating my own extension and would like to also register additional endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two key components to registering endpoints for an Azure Functions extension.

1. A call to `context.GetWebhookHandler()` as found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/bf9a9b29fccae849840686459175b7d8ae619f67/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskExtension.cs#L162).
2. The extension must implement `IAsyncConverter<HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>` as found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/blob/bf9a9b29fccae849840686459175b7d8ae619f67/src/WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/DurableTaskExtension.cs#L37).

When both of these conditions are met, the Functions runtime will forward all requests in the API namespace `runtime/webhooks/<extension-name>*` to the implementation of `IAsyncConverter<HttpRequestMessage, HttpResponseMessage>`. If you look at the Durable Task framework as an example, the `HttpApiHandler` then looks at the path and methods of those requests to route the requests to the proper API methods.

There is no way to register endpoints outside of the `runtime/webhooks/<extension-name>*` namespace. However, you can create as many endpoints within that namespace as you would like. You as the extension developer are responsible for routing those `HttpRequestMessage` objects to the API logic for that endpoint though.